# Unable to pop top element from the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to make a simple Linked List program, also when I'm trying to pop the first element from the list , it's not popping and it still remains the first element in the list, please help me resolve this error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create(stack *s){
 if(s == NULL){
    s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack)*1);
    (s->next)=NULL;
 }
 else{
    stack *temp = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack)*1);
    (temp->next)=s;
    s=temp;
 }
}

void push(stack *s, char x){
   create(s);
   (s->value)=x;
}

void isEmpty(stack *s){
    if(s == NULL){
        printf("List is Empty!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("List is not Empty!\n");
    }
}

char pop(stack *s){
 if(s == NULL){
    isEmpty(s);
    return -1;
 }
 char x=s->value;
 s=(s->next);
 return x;
}   

int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
stack *s;
create(s);
char choice,data;
printf("Stack Created\n\n");
do{
    printf("Choose Option: pUsh, pOp, pEek, iseMpty, getSize, eXit: \n");

    scanf(" %c",&choice);

    switch(choice){
        case 'U':{
            printf("Enter the element to be pushed: \n");

            scanf(" %c",&data);
            push(s, data);
            break;
        }
        case 'O':{
            data=pop(s);
            if(data != NULL){
                printf("Popped: %c\n", data);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}while(1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the pop() code too

Comment: check it again, i've edited the code

Comment: Your code is a real mess bro ... u even didnt free the memory u allocated you can find stack implementation in my github account

Comment: [stacks implementation](https://github.com/aliakberfaiz/C-and-Cpp-programs-/blob/master/DS/stacksUsingStructures.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the argument to `pop()` and `push()` from `stack *` to `stack **`, so that we can update the stack not a local variable. I removed `create()` as it is basically what happens during the push and I integrated it with that. 
The rest is straightforward and I also added the `free()` call in `pop()`. Take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack{
  int value;
  struct stack *next;
}stack;

void push(stack **s, int x){
  stack *temp = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack)*1);
  temp->value = x;
  temp->next = NULL;
  if(*s == NULL){
    *s = temp;
  }else{ 
    temp->next = *s;
    *s=temp;
  }
}

char pop(stack **s){
  if(*s == NULL){
    return -1;
  }
  char x=(*s)->value;
  stack *tmp = *s;
  *s=(*s)->next;
  free(tmp);
  return x;
}   

int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
  stack *s;
  char choice,data;
  printf("Stack Created\n\n");
  do{
    printf("Choose Option: pUsh, pOp, pEek, iseMpty, getSize, eXit: \n");
    scanf(" %c",&choice);

    switch(choice){
      case 'U':{
        printf("Enter the element to be pushed: \n");

        scanf(" %c",&data);
        push(&s, data);
        break;
      }
      case 'O':{
        data=pop(&s);
        if(data != -1){
            printf("Popped: %c\n", data);
        } else {
            printf("Stack is empty. nothing popped");
        }
        break;
      }
   }
 }while(1);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The line `s=s->next;` has no effect because `s` is a local varaible.  You need to return the new value of `s` or use pointers to modify the caller's version.

Comment: shouldn't he free the memory he allocated ? just a thought ?

Comment: why? s is a pointer and thus pop() becomes a call by reference function, therefore it's value should change.

Comment: @AashishKumar There is no such thing as "call by reference" in C.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have to use pointer to pointer if u want to pass pointer as an argument

```
char pop(stack **s)
{
 **s=s->next;
}
```

this is a temporary solution u should also consider deleting the memory you allocated using the malloc function or else it will lead to memory leak 
also pass the address of the pointer s while you call it in the pop function